# Combine emacs merge diffs without origin information

Tags: emacs

How can I combine the diffs of two buffers into a third without the "<<<<<<< variant" strings? Basically I want to have both sources one after another without any extra stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Change [`ediff-combination-pattern`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ediff/Merging-and-diff3.html), either through the Customize interface (“Customize Ediff” menu entry, “Ediff Merge” group), or with Lisp code like

```
(setq ediff-combination-pattern
      '("" A "" B "####### Ancestor" Ancestor ""))
```

There will still be an empty line around the blocks. As of Emacs 23.2, this is built into `ediff-get-combined-region'.

Alternatively, remove the markers afterwards with

```
M-x flush-lines RET
^\(<<<<<<<\|>>>>>>>\|=======\) RET
```